# What are some common approaches for handling the UI layer in Java web applications?

Tags: java, content-management-system

I have an application with a Java back-end.  I wanted to use Drupal CMS and that required Apache installation for PHP, which was ok.

But I am wondering what are some better ways to handle the UI layer in Java-based applications?

I remember some time ago I used a templating framework on top of Spring.  But there was a designer who created nice templates.  Ideally I would use something out of the box that would look professional.

Any tips? Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good discussion on various java templating frameworks:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174204/suggestions-for-a-java-based-templating-engine

I like velocity.  To get something professional you have to put in the work and make some nice CSS / HTML design.  Or you can steal the design from somewhere like http://www.csszengarden.com.  Once you have that, any of the templating frameworks will help you make the design dynamic in no time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what is already built-up using java as backend and how you want to integrate the CMS with it. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you might find [this](http://java-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems) helpful and here are few related SO Q&A on java based CMS

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419968/best-open-source-java-cms
- [What do you consider the best CMS in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100089/what-do-you-consider-the-best-cms-in-java)